# Change name of file based upon time

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a project where I need to rename an image file based upon the time. I am trying this using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), but there are some limitations occurring in my application.

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:" %%d in ("%time%") do ( 
    set num=%%d-%%e-%%f
)
ren img.png %num%.png
```

Comment: How is your batch file related to c++ or dev-c++?

Comment: So you are asking us to rewrite the batch code into [`c++`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)?

Comment: What are the limitations? What happens when you run the code that is not what you've written it to do? Are you aware that `%TIME%` can output a completely different string for two different users on the same PC, and on different PC's? Is this your issue? If it is, there are hundreds of examples of this site to show you how you can retrieve a locale/PC independent date or time. Please search.

Comment: I make a batch file of this code, And Write As system("call mybatchfile.bat"); its work great with Dev C++ Code @Klaus

Comment: Yes Exactly  @GerhardBarnard

Comment: The limitation is that when I need to fetch data from a text file using dev c++ code in a string. I Need to write this string As system("package.exe string "); that not to be possible .@Compo

Comment: No , Only   for that pc which the code run @Compo

Comment: I search but I did not find the solution  @Compo

Comment: You say you have some limitations using batch file. Can you please elaborate what the limitation is?

Comment: I am Making my Application part in Dev C++, Where I Performing some tasks using the batch file. You Can say a specific coding task I am performing in a batch file, But Batch file data that store in a text file and later store in a dev C++ string cannot be Connected As a system("package.exe string);  Limitation Occouring in Application Algo, And Batch file is Connected with My Application @GerhardBarnard